# How do I read messages after scanning them?

Tags: zombiu

In one of the first areas of ZombiU after leaving the safehouse, I found a message seemingly left by another player while scanning on the gamepad. It said the message was added after I scanned it, but I couldn't find a way to read it when I checked the menu.

How do I read messages after I scan them?

[image: Scanned message on gamepad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These messages are wall graffiti that are only visible when scanning with the gamepad. Marking a message will increase the "don't trust" counter by one.

Wall on TV when not scanning
[image: wall when not scanning]

Wall on gamepad when scanning
[image: same wall on gamepad]